# Ambiguity of Remove Method in Java ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Generally, the usage of remove method for ArrayList in Java is shown as below:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("abc");
list.add("efg");

list.remove(1);   //Removing the second element in ArrayList.
list.remove("abc");  //Removing the element with the value "abc" in ArrayList.
```

However, there is situation where overloading doesn't work.

```
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

numbers.add(1);
   numbers.add(2);
when I tried to remove the element with value 2. It gives me error:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2
    at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
    at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:387)
```

So it looks like when it comes to remove number, I can't remove element with specific value. Because the computer would assume all the integer value as index, not the value of element.

**It is a subtle error. Is there any other simple way to delete the element with specific integer value?**

Comment: Use an `Integer` object.

Comment: @Kon Can you give a simple example about that?

Comment: you can remove using `numbers.remove(new Integer(2));`

Comment: @HaoyuChen Added it as an answer

Comment: @HaoyuChen No problem, glad to help. You may be further interested in reading about widening and boxing in Java method overloading hierarchy. It's a good thing to understand :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use an `Integer` object.

```
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    numbers.add(5);
    numbers.add(10);
    numbers.remove(new Integer(5));
    System.err.println(numbers);
    //Prints [10]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `remove(new Integer(1)`. This will work as it ll be a exact match to `remove(Object o)`

Answer (score 0):

Normally you are not removing a hardcoded number, but a variable value. Therefore it is better to use
`Integer.valueOf(yourIntVar)`.
This way you use an existing object rather than creating a new one.